# javascript select menu typeError

Tags: javascript, html

i am facing an issue with below mentioned code. The errors are **'aggiungiPrimaOpzione typeError: cannot read property insertBefore of null'** and **'inizializza typeError: cannot set property onchange of undefined'**.
it also provides a sintaxError: http://i68.tinypic.com/2zdodj5.png

```
var nodoGenere;
var nodoCategoria;
var nodoCerca;
var nodoRisultato;

var collezione = [
{
    genere: "uomo",
    categoria: "maglietta",
    nome: "maglietta1",
    foto: "img/foto1.jpg",
    prezzo: 40
},
{
    genere: "donna",
    categoria: "pantaloni",
    nome: "pantalone1",
    foto: "img/foto2.jpg",
    prezzo: 50
}
];

function gestoreGenere(){
try {
    var genere = nodoGenere.value;
    var generi = calcolaGenere();
    creaSelect(nodoGenere, generi);
    nodoGenere.value = genere;
    var categorie = ricercaCategoria(genere);
    creaSelect(nodoCategoria, categorie);
    aggiungiPrimaOpzione(nodoCategoria, "----- categoria ----");
} catch(e) {
    alert("gestoreGenere" + e);
}
}

function ricercaCategoria(genere) {
try {
    var categorie = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < collezione.length; i++) {
        var abito = collezione[i];
        if (abito.genere == genere) {
            categorie[abito.genere] = true;
        }
    }
    return categorie;
} catch(e) {
    alert("ricercaCategoria" + e);
}
}

function aggiungiPrimaOpzione(nodoSelect, opzione) {
try {
    var nodoOpzione = document.createElement("option");
    nodoOpzione.value = opzione;
    var nodoTesto = document.createTextNode(opzione);
    nodoOpzione.appendChild(nodoTesto);
    nodoSelect.insertBefore(nodoOpzione, nodoSelect.firstChild);
    nodoSelect.value = opzione;
} catch(e) {
    alert("aggiungiPrimaOpzione" + e);
}
}

function gestoreCategoria() {
try {
    var genere = nodoGenere.value;
    var categoria = nodoCategoria.value;
    var categorie = ricercaCategoria(categoria);
    creaSelect(nodoCategoria, categorie);
    nodoCategoria.value = categoria;
    var abiti = ricercaMultipla(genere, categoria);
    var listaDescrizioni = calcolaListaDescrizioni(abiti);
    creaLista(nodoRisultato, listaDescrizioni);
} catch(e) {
    alert("gestoreCategoria" + e);
}
}

function calcolaListaDescrizioni(abiti) {
try {
    var listaDescrizioni = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < abiti.length; i++){
        var abito = abiti[i];
        var s = abito.categoria + "dio cane" + abito.genere;
        listaDescrizioni.push(s);
    }
    return listaDescrizioni;
} catch(e) {
    alert("calcolaListaDescrizioni" + e);
}
}

function ricercaMultipla(genere, categoria) {
try {
    var abiti = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < collezione.length; i++) {
        var abito = collezione[i];
        if (abito.genere == genere && abito.categoria == categoria) {
         abiti.push(abito);
        }
    }
    return abiti;
} catch(e) {
    alert("ricercaMultipla" + e);
}
}

function calcolaGenere() {
try {
    var generi = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < collezione.length; i++) {
        var abito = collezione[i];
        generi[abito.genere] = true;
    }
    return generi;
} catch(e) {
    alert("calcolaGenere" + e);
}
}

function calcolaCategorie() {
try {
    var categorie = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < collezione.length; i++) {
        var abito = collezione[i];
        categorie[abito.categoria] = true;
    }
    return categorie;
} catch(e) {
    alert("calcolaCategorie" + e);
}
}

function creaSelect(nodoSelect, opzioni) {
try {
    rimuoviFigli(nodoSelect);
    for (var opzione in opzioni) {
        var nodoOpzione = document.createElement("option");
        nodoOpzione.value = opzione;
        var nodoTesto = document.createTextNode(opzione);
        nodoOpzione.appendChild(nodoTesto);
        nodoSelect.appendChild(nodoOpzione);
    }
} catch(e) {
    alert("creaSelect" + e);
}
}

function creaLista(nodoLista, elementi) {
try {
    rimuoviFigli(nodoLista);
    for (var i = 0; i < elementi.length; i++) {
        var elemento = elementi[i];
        var nodoElemento = document.createElement("li");
        nodoLista.appendChild(nodoElemento);
        var nodoTesto = document.createTextNode(elemento);
        nodoElemento.appendChild(nodoTesto);
    }
} catch(e) {
    alert("creaLista" + e);
}
}

function rimuoviFigli(nodo){
while (nodo.childNodes.lenght > 0) {
    nodo.removeChild(nodo.firstChild);
}
}

function inizializza() {
try {
    var nodoGenere = document.getElementById("genere");
    var nodoCategoria = document.getElementById("categoria");
    var nodoRisultato = document.getElementById("risultato");
    var genere = calcolaGenere();
    creaSelect(nodoGenere, genere);
    aggiungiPrimaOpzione(nodoGenere, "----- genere ----");
    aggiungiPrimaOpzione(nodoCategoria, "---- categoria ----");
    nodoGenere.onchange = gestoreGenere;
    nodoCategoria.onchange = gestoreCategoria;
} catch(e) {
    alert("inizializza" + e);
}
}

window.onload = inizializza;
```

and the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title> prova </title>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="genere"></select>
    <select id="categoria"></select>
    <input type="button" id="cerca" value="cerca">
   <div id="risultato"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advice for your response.

Comment: It is hard to understand because of non-english content

Comment: Are you trying to invoke the `function nodoGenere.onchange = gestoreGenere;`? Because you're not, you're only assigning it. Try `gestoreGenere()`;

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: you are trying to insert some element before nonexistent object
nodoSelect.insertBefore(nodoOpzione, nodoSelect.firstChild)
try use jquery $(nodoSelect).prepend(nodoOpzione)

Comment: i need a solution without jquery